# How do you make the music keep going even when going to a new ViewController in Swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to play a mp3 file in a `UIViewController`. Though, when the user leaves the view controller the music stops. How do I keep it playing?

```
var alertSound: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("musicFileHere", ofType: "mp3")!)!
var error: NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
```

Comment: Under your last line if you add audioPlayer.play that should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That didn't work.

Comment: Isn't it possible, that the viewcontroller, that start to play the audio, gets deallocated when the new viewcontroller instantiated?

Comment: I don't know. Thanks for your input though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `audioPlayer.play` so your whole code looks like this:

```
var alertSound: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("musicFileHere", ofType: "mp3")!)!
var error: NSError?
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: alertSound, error: &error)
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()   
audioPlayer.play
```